# How to set model data in Reactive Forms, Angular 9

Tags: html, css, angular, spring, typescript

I started to study angular, i created a single crud using Angular 9 and Spring boot, but i have a  question, what I'm trying to do is to get the data of the table below and move it for a reactive form to upload the data.
How to solve the issue?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0soBG.png)
.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vNse.png)

```html
 <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="">Nome</label>
          <input type="text" formControlName="nome" class="form-control">
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="">email</label>
          <input type="text" formControlName="email" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="">username</label>
          <input type="text" formControlName="username" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <button  class="btn btn-outline-primary"> Salvar</button>
        <button [routerLink]="['/']" style="margin-left: 1%;"  class="btn btn-outline-warning"> Voltar</button>

      </form>
```

My app-routing.module.ts:

```html
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ShowContactComponent } from './Componets/contact/show-contact/show-contact.component'
import { CreateContactComponent } from './Componets/contact/create-contact/create-contact.component'

const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'', component:ShowContactComponent},
  {path:'create', component:CreateContactComponent},
  {path:'create/:id', component:CreateContactComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Contact } from '../contact-model/Contact';
import { ContactService } from '../../contact.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-contact',
  templateUrl: './create-contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-contact.component.css']
})
export class CreateContactComponent implements OnInit {

  form:FormGroup;
  contacts:Contact[] = []
  contact:Contact
  constructor(private service:ContactService, private router:Router, private fb:FormBuilder, private AR:ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // this.paramService();
    this.validateForms();
  }

  submit(){
    const formValue = this.form.value;
    const contact:Contact = new Contact(formValue.nome,  formValue.email ,formValue.username );  
    this.service.create(contact).subscribe(response =>{
      this.contacts.push(response);
      this.router.navigate([''])
      console.log(response);
    })
  }


  paramService(){
    const formValue = this.form.value;
    const contact:Contact = new Contact(formValue.nome,  formValue.email ,formValue.username ); 
    console.log(contact);
    this.service.readOne(this.contact.id).subscribe(response =>{
      
      
      this.form.patchValue({
        nome: contact.nome,
        email: contact.email,
        username: contact.username
      });
    });
  }
    
  

  validateForms(){
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      nome: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      username: ['', Validators.required]
    })
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in this way:

```
validateForms(data?: Contact){
   this.form = this.fb.group({
     nome: [data.name || '', Validators.required],
     email: [data.email || '', Validators.required],
     username: [data.username || '', Validators.required]
   })
}
```

Now you should pass the data to show in your form:

```
ngOnInit() {
   // const contact: Contact = ...
   this.validateForms(contact);
}
```

Please change 'validateForms' name to 'initForm'.